# xterm smooth sizing

Tags: terminal

How do I configure xterm to resize smoothly and not by character increments?

Or is there another teminal app that will resize smoothly?

Comment: This question doesn't belong on serverfault. It's asking about how to make cosmetic customizations of an app that runs on your desktop.

Comment: sorry for that then, wasn't sure if it falls under stack overflow. It's a configuration issue, so I figured it falls under server fault more. My bad :(

Comment: It wouldn't belong on StackOverflow, but on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. xterm even tells xwindows that it's a char-cell sized app. And I don't think smoothly sized terms are very common either. (I don't see the point either, it's a very char based system, from teletypes onward..)

Comment: Of course, if you're willing to look for extremely perverse hackish solutions, those might exist. I know there's a program called 'blast' that installs and messes with a transparency bitmap for other programs' windows...

Comment: I have done it before with out allot of hacking. The reason is the tiling window manager gives xterm its space, but xterm only size to the characters, so most of the time there is a 2 pixel gap between it and the other windows.

Comment: This is typically why tiling window managers allow you to decide whether to obey applications "resize hints".  If you tell the WM to ignore those hints, then you applications like xterm can be sized however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `konsole`?  It resizes smoothly, if I understand your question correctly.